# Nginx location block and performance

Tags: magento, nginx, redirect, nginx-location

I am not an expert with Nginx, so I read several articles and the official guideline to get myself up to speed. However, I found nothing that touch base on the location vs rewrite block performance.

My scenario is the following: an existing website changed their english URLs into Chinese, and I have to prevent any loss of traffic for several URLs.

I came up with two working configuration, though this was limited to just a few URLs and I wasn't able to test on any production or pre-production environment to validate the effectiveness.

**Solution A)**

`Use n+1 rewrite blocks followed by a permanent flag straight in the server block;`

**Solution B)**

`Use n+1 exact location blocks with a nested rewrite and permanent flag followed by a break;`

Both solutions have a catch all rule that redirect to an index.php file to allow Magento process the request and produce the output.

My understanding is that solution B may be more efficient thanks to the break instruction that will prevent additional rewriting rule to be executed, forwarding the rewrite module straight to the location blocks.
As I have only one of them - a catch all - there is very little choice here.

Given the above, is it correct assuming the solution B is more correct?

Comment: Unless I'm not wrong, the solution B is more efficient. One note though, you cannot use the an exact location block, otherwise you will not be shown the 301 redirection you would expect to save your SEO (as I imagine this is the scope of your exercise). You need to use either the "~*" or the "~" modifier respectively for the case-sensitive or insensitive matching.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Nginx much more efficient in testing static location than regexp's

Comment: @Enigmativity if you are voting to close this down, you should IMHO close and remove the other 53K results related to Nginx.

Comment: @AndreaMoro - if they are off-topic then sure. Is your question programming related?

Comment: @Enigmativity That's not my question. But as far as I can see it, writing a config file for creating redirection has some elements of coding. So IMO it is relevant.

Comment: @AndreaMoro - From the [help/on-topic] page - "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools."

Comment: well, sorry for having posted the question in the wrong place. Can you please move into a related forum for me to get the right support?